# Check in to ClearCase fails

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am trying to add a file into ClearCase, but I am getting the following error:

> Error adding 'C:\PATH\file.dbc' to source control.
>
> Changed Protection on "C:\PATH\file.dbc".
>
> Created branch "C:\PATH\file.dbc" version "\main\0".
>
> Type manager "text_file_delta" failed create_version operation.

Checked the following:
There are lines that have over 8000 characters and they must stay that way, so it can not use the "text_file_delta" as the type manager.  I changed the type of one file to "compressed_file" and I was able to check it in.

I tried to add `dbc compressed_file -name "*.[dD][bB][cC]" ;` to the default.magic file.  Then, I tried to check it with `ct file test.dbc` and it said that it is a compressed_file, but when I try to add an actual .dbc file to source control, it still gives me the error about the "text_file_delta" failing.

Is there something that I am missing with this?  Maybe I put the line in the wrong part of the default.magic file?

Note:  the only default.magic file that I am able to find is on the server side, is this correct?  (I would rather it check here instead of everyone having to make one on their client.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the default.magic file is taken into account, and is in the right directory, as mentioned in "[About the ClearCase Magic file](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21122471)".

Make sure you did add the new rule in the right place in that magic file: see "[How file types are determined when creating a new element](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21118099#Table3)"

> Note: **This is the *first* section in the `default.magic` file**.
>
> Example:

```
# Match by name without examining data
core file : -name "core" ;
compressed_file : -name "*.[nN][eE][wW]";
```

> Note: The new file-typing rule that you add must come before the following line in the magic file:

```
text_file : -printable ;
compressed_file : !-printable ;
```

Use a personal magic file rather than modifying the default one:

> Caution: It is highly recommended that you not modify the `default.magic` file directly as the next time an upgrade is performed, a new `default.magic` file will be created and your changes will be lost.
> Creating a personal magic file with a name that is alphabetically before the "d" in the `default.magic` file name (such as `cc.magic`) will allow ClearCase to parse this file before the default.
> It is better to create a personal magic file and possibly setting the `MAGIC_PATH` variable instead.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I followed what that site said (though, this time I created a cc.magic on the server) and it still isn't making the *.dbc files as a compressed_file.  I put the line above "core file..."  Do I have to restart anything?  I need to figure this out so I can get these files checked in quickly.  Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @Rubasu I suppose you made it work, but if not, you can, as a workaround, for the type on the "add to source control" with a "`cleartool mkelem -eltype ...`".