# Clearcase issue while "add file to source control"

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am facing a following issue while adding a file to clearcase (UCM)

```
---------------------------
Rational ClearCase Explorer
---------------------------
Error adding 'M:\Myviename\Myvob\Myproj\Implementation\DataSource\Deployment\BOM\SupportFiles\Service.config' to source control.

Created branch "Tm6-Proj-Dev2" from M:\Myviename\Myvob\Myproj\Implementation\DataSource\Deployment\BOM\SupportFiles\Service.config' version "\main\0".
Type manager "text_file_delta" failed create_version operation.
```

I tried rebase and deleted and added the file again. But facing the same. Why this occured and how to solve it?

Comment: Did you try contatcing IBM support: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21222072

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will find all the know cases for this error message in [this technote "Knowledge Collection: Type manager `<text_file_delta>` failed create_version operation"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21259086)

- Type manager size limitation - File too large
- Text files that contain binary data - Contains a '\000'
- Line exceeding 8000 bytes
- Corrupt source container - not the highest on its branch

The main cause is a content incompatible with a text file (line too long, or binary content).

---

The [OP Samselvaprabu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/399145/samselvaprabu) adds:

> Our IT guys used the following command "`chtype Compressed_file`".
> After that it allowed to check-in.
>
> As they did it in my collegue system, I was not able to ask what does this mean and how it solved the issue?

It does solve the issue (and it has nothing to do with UCM): since the text_manager doesn't recognized the content of the file as text (as illustrated, for instance, [in this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?&rs=984&uid=swg21146932)), you need to instruct ClearCase to treat it as binary content.

```
cleartool chtype compressed_file <filename>
```

- **Pro**: it allows for checkin/checkouts
- **Cons**: you won't be able to "compare with previous version" anymore.
  You might need to instruct that compressed_file to be always copied over instead of merged (see "[Clearcase UCM is trying to merge pdf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789258/clearcase-ucm-is-trying-to-merge-pdf-files)")

For certain set of files, you could also modify the magic file to automate that process: see "[Check in to ClearCase fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438975/check-in-to-clearcase-fails)".

Comment: Our IT guys used the following command "chtype Compressed_file".After that it allowed to check-in . As they did it in my collegue system i was not able to ask what does this mean and how it solved the issue? As you are an experienced UCM user, Do you have any idea why it could have solved the issue?

Comment: @SamselvaprabuI have edited my answer to answer your comment.

Comment: I ran into this problem with one of my users for a minified javascript file (Line exceeding 8000 bytes).  My users submit clearcase files via a script and to fix the situation I run all files through either:  `file --brief "file to test"` and it will respond with `ASCII text, with very long lines`.  Another alternative is to use `wc -L < "file to test"` then you can decide how long is too long. Clearcase gets upset at 8000 characters.

Answer (score -1):

Which type of view are you using ? Static(Snapshot) or Dynamic ?
check if file is already there on the main. 
If the file is already there on main (which means file is Versioned file) then before editing you should check-out file and then after making changes you need to check in.
If you are using versioned file and you if made changes to this versioned file then it will be a hijacked file, (you will see red+green mark for on the file in clear case explorer). 
Try out once.