# Clear Case. How to split very long javascript on multiple lines?

Tags: javascript, clearcase

I have a JS compressed file which is long about 14k and it is on one single line. This creates some problem on Clear Case, making check in impossible

Is there a way to fix clearcase?

If I whant to split the JS file on multiple lines, should I pay attention to something when inserting line breaks. Obviously I won't split a string or anumber, after that any other non obvious thing to keep in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about ClearCase. A safe place to split is after a `;` or `}` outside of a string constant since there shouldn't be any comments in compressed JS.

You can also split the file manually; the file probably doesn't change often and 10 line feeds more or less won't hurt the performance.

Answer (score 4):

The other solution would be to change the type of your compressed JS file to... "compressed_file":

```
cleartool chtype Compressed_file
```

That way, you wouldn't have to modify your file.
See "[Clearcase issue while “add file to source control”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074369/clearcase-issue-while-add-file-to-source-control)" for more on that technique.

You can also specify the merge manager to always copy over that file when merged, to avoid any merge issue. See "[Clearcase UCM is trying to merge pdf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789258/clearcase-ucm-is-trying-to-merge-pdf-files)".

Comment: Actually it is a compressed js  into a JSP file. Anyway good idea. I can always put the JS outside the jsp

Comment: @Paolo yes, isolating the issue in its own file would be best, as it would allow the Version Control tool to manage it more appropriately (`compressed_file`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, line-breaks have a syntactic meaning in JS. A javascript instruction is terminated either by a semicolon or a line-break (or, what's usually the case, both). When the whole script was written without linebreaks, the only way to separate the instructions were semicolons. So when you add a line-break after every semicolon, the syntactical meaning should stay the same.

But are you sure that you should check-in the compressed Javascript code and not the original, uncompressed version? Especially when you have to edit it to do so? Artifacts, like compiled binaries, usually don't belong into version control. A compressed JS file should also be treated like that, in my opinion.