# Clearcase Remote Client add minified file (8000 chars in a line)

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I have some minified files that I'm trying to add to ClearCase via the remote client.
Apparently these files are failing due to a large number characters in one line.

I found a solution if one is using the full client [here](http://kitmenke.com/blog/2013/01/23/adding-minified-javascriptcss-files-to-clearcase/), but I'm not sure how to make this happen in the remote client.

What would be the right process to create those files as `compressed_file`?

Answer (score 0):

I mention the same issue in "[Clearcase issue while “add file to source control”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12075051/6309)" and "[ClearCase. How to split very long javascript on multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12351243/6309)".

The solution which consists to mkelem an element with the type `compressed_file` should be possible with [ccrc, using rcleartool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21577362/6309), which include [`rcleartool mkelem`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkelem.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-37).