# How to avoid clearcase to have never_merge_binary element type?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Every time I create an element, it is created with the "`never_merge_binary`" element type.

How can I avoid this in future to have it "`compressed_file`" rather than "`never_merge_binary`"?
What param in `C:\Program Files\Rational\ClearCase\config\magic\default.magic` does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as I mention in "[Check in to ClearCase fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11439527/6309)", don't modify directly the `default.magic` file.

> Creating a personal magic file with a name that is alphabetically before the "`d`" in the default.magic file name (such as `cc.magic`) will allow ClearCase to parse this file before the default.

Then, define a new type FILE_COPY_MERGE type as described in "[Clearcase UCM is trying to merge pdf files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8789593/6309)", and change your files with that new type (as well as declaring it in `cc.magic`).
More in "[Handling binary files in ClearCase](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21123371)".